# how to convert b/w image (png, jpg) to vector form? (.EPS, .SVG)

Tags: inkscape, vector, svg, raster, eps

how to convert b/w image (png, jpg) to vector form (.EPS, .SVG) without artifacts? The raster image is geometric vector patterns, I need convert it into vector form. I tried some online image to .svg converters, but resulting .svg show some artifacts visible. The original .png image have clean vector patterns, without artifacts.

I mean monochrome images, example:

[image]

Comment: No such thing as **png** with *vector* patterns. Ultimately converting any raster image to vector, no matter how "clean" you think the raster image is, will almost always necessitate some manual clean up after the tracing. There is almost *never* 1:1 quality when tracing.

Comment: In Inkscape, import the PNG image, select it, and do *Path > Trace Bitmap*. Without seeing your image, I can't really give you any suggestions regarding settings. You might want to share the image. Success will depend on the complexity and quality of the image.  Auto tracing is rarely perfect however.

Comment: I mean monochrome b/w images like [this](https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/005/050/877/small_2x/black-and-white-greek-ornate-tangled-round-frame-template-free-vector.jpg)

Comment: @LexxLuxx - thanks for the image link. I can answer now

Comment: I don't know about Inkscape, but with Illustrator, it is a very simple thing to create a Pattern Brush and apply it to a circle... [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Pe2.png) No need to trace anything.

Comment: it can actually be faster to draw the patterns since they are simple and geometric in nature: [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2te3d.png) -- I *don't* honestly know if Inkscape has anything comparable to a pattern brush though.

Comment: @Scott - yes you could easily use the pattern on a path LPE in Inkscape, to recreate it in Inkscape. This functionality is similar to a pattern brush in Illustrator, . That's what I would do. It would be better than any auto tracing.

Comment: The convert tools does not recognize pattern like circles and redraws them in the most efficient way. Instead, paths are identified, maybe in very high resolution, if the source is of high resolution. To get a result without staircases in some zoom level, you have to rebuild it.

Comment: Here's a demo of pattern along path LPE on Inkscape by Nick Saporito. Auto-tracing bitmaps always creates imperfections so, if artifacts are unacceptable, manually recreating patterns is the better alternative. https://youtu.be/3jve45Z60iU

Answer (score 1):

The default trace settings in Inkscape should manage this just fine.  Select the raster image, and click *Path > Trace Bitmap*.

An example: Trace is on the left, original on the right. I increased the Threshold a little to 520. Click to see at full size.

[image]

Tracing is rarely perfect though. A higher resolution image (with more pixels) would be better. Ultimately redrawing manually would be the best method, assuming you have the skills to recreate it obviously.

After you have finished, select and delete the raster image. Then save the SVG.

Comment: Although the traced image looks sharp, but when zoom it a bit, it's visible that corners inside the patterns are not rectangular 90°, but slightly rounded. So seems the artifacts can't be completely avoided.